# How to email attachment with Flask wtf Form?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to send attachment via form, form itself loads and sends email fine when msg.attach is removed but as soon active drops out AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'

This is app file, name routes.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, url_for, redirect
from forms import ContactForm
from flask_mail import Message, Mail
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm



app = Flask(__name__)

# configurations
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisismysecret'
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.office365.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'login@server.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'

mail = Mail(app)
maisend ="sender@mail.com"
mailreceive ="receipment@server.com"



@app.route('/index')
def index():
return render_template('index.html', title='Flask Index', success=True)

@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def contactForm():
 form = ContactForm()
  if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
  elif request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
        flash('All fields are required !')
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
        msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender= maisend, recipients= [mailreceive])
        msg.body = """
        from: %s &lt;%s&gt
         %s
        """% (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
    msg.attach(
    form.file.data.filename,'application/octet-stream',
    form.file.data.read())
    mail.send(msg)

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return '<h1>Form submitted!</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

When this part is removed works perfectly

```
msg.attach(
 form.file.data.filename,'application/octet-stream',
 form.file.data.read())
```

and this is form file

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextAreaField, SubmitField, TextField, FileField
from wtforms import ValidationError, validators
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired


class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
 name = TextField("Name", [validators.DataRequired('Please enter your name !')])
 email = TextField("Email")
 subject = TextField("Subject", [validators.DataRequired('Please enter a Subject !')])
 message = TextAreaField("Message", [validators.DataRequired('Enter a message !')])
 file = FileField("Some file")
 submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

NO clue what is causing issue, I dont want file to be saved at server, maybe as temp but deleted after success, and I dont want make attachment mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment as I don't have enough reputation, so it's a stab in the dark. Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? Flask-WTF docs say that unless you have the correct enctype, the file field `data` attribute will be `None`.